# Начать игру по нажатию ENTER!

Tags: c#

Это код игры в WindowsForm. При открытии игра сразу начинает работать но нужно что бы было по нажатию ENTER, как это сделать это я не понял

```
namespace OdevProje
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int moveLeft = 0;
        int enemyMove = 2;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int bulletSpeed = 15;
        bool shooting = false;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            dusman1.Top = -500;
            dusman2.Top = -500;
            dusman3.Top = -500;
            dusman4.Top = -500;
            dusman5.Top = -500;
            dusman6.Top = -500;
            dusman7.Top = -500;
            mermer.Top = -100;
            mermer.Left = -100;
        }

        private void tusaBasldgnda(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                if (tabanca.Location.X < 0)
                {
                    moveLeft = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    moveLeft = -8;
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                if (tabanca.Location.X > 935)
                {
                    moveLeft = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    moveLeft = 8;
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {

                if (shooting == false)
                {
                    bulletSpeed = 15;
                    mermer.Left = tabanca.Left + 10;
                    mermer.Top = tabanca.Top;
                    shooting = true;
                }
            }  
        }

        private void tusBrakldgnda(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                moveLeft = 0;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                moveLeft = 0;
            }
        }

        private void oyunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                tabanca.Left += moveLeft;
                mermer.Top -= bulletSpeed;
                dusman1.Top += enemyMove;
                dusman2.Top += enemyMove;
                dusman3.Top += enemyMove;
                dusman4.Top += enemyMove;
                dusman5.Top += enemyMove;
                dusman6.Top += enemyMove;
                dusman7.Top += enemyMove;



            if (dusman1.Top == 560 || dusman2.Top == 560 || dusman3.Top == 560 || dusman4.Top == 560 || dusman5.Top == 560 || dusman6.Top == 560 || dusman7.Top == 560)
            {
                gameOver();

            }

            if (shooting && mermer.Top < 0)
            {
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;
            }
            enemyHit();
        }
        private void enemyHit()
        {
            if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman1.Bounds))
            {
                dusman1.Top = -500;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 300);
                dusman1.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }
            else if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman2.Bounds))
            {
                dusman2.Top = -650;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 400);
                dusman2.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }
            else if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman3.Bounds))
            {
                dusman3.Top = -660;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 600);
                dusman3.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }
            else if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman4.Bounds))
            {
                dusman4.Top = -420;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 630);
                dusman4.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }
            else if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman5.Bounds))
            {
                dusman5.Top = -1300;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 620);
                dusman5.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }
            else if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman6.Bounds))
            {
                dusman6.Top = -700;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 600);
                dusman6.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }
            else if (mermer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(dusman7.Bounds))
            {
                dusman7.Top = -680;
                int ranP = rnd.Next(1, 600);
                dusman7.Left = ranP;
                shooting = false;
                bulletSpeed = 0;
                mermer.Top = -100;
                mermer.Left = -100;

            }

        }
        private void gameOver()
        {
            oyunTimer.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show(" Click OK to play Again");
            dusman1.Top = -500;
            dusman2.Top = -650;
            dusman3.Top = -660;
            dusman4.Top = -420;
            dusman5.Top = -700;
            dusman6.Top = -680;
            dusman7.Top = 720;
            mermer.Top = -100;
            mermer.Left = -100;
            oyunTimer.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не удивлен,что вы не поняли. Код-то не ваш. Тут обрабатываются только нажатия `Keys.Left`, `Keys.Right`, `Keys.Space`.

Comment: Я не сильно опытный в сфере, но хочу предложить =) Что если по нажатию кнопки в одной форме открыть форму с игрой?

Comment: где у вас запускается oyunTimer ?

Comment: @codename0082016 игра запускается сразу. oyunTimer (Timer) я просто перетащил его из Toolbox.

Comment: Ну так перетащи с Toolbox кнопку и на её клик назнач старт игры

Comment: @AGS17 да код не мой я его на просторах инета нашел. С нуля писать времени нет. Заранее извините.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто еще один Timer добавить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  и как его переназначить?

Comment: tusBrakldgnda - ужаснее этого имени метода-обработчика события я еще не видел.

Comment: @MansurMahmutov _С нуля писать времени нет._ - так если нет времени писать с нуля, так хоть с тем, что скачали разобрались бы самостоятельно

Comment: @AGS17 Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из имеющегося кода видно, что в двух обработчиках с невозможно говорящими названиями `tusaBasldgnda()` и `tusBrakldgnda()` присутствует обработка нажатий клавиш `Keys.Left`, `Keys.Right` и `Keys.Space`.

Вам требуется добавить обработку клавиши `Keys.Return`. Боюсь предположить на какие объекты привязаны обработчики `tusaBasldgnda()` и `tusBrakldgnda()`, поэтому предложу повесить хендлер на все окно. Не забываем установить свойство [`Form.KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) в `true`. Также могу предположить, что таймер `oyunTimer` при старте уже включен, поэтому его после инициализации компонентов окна надо его остановить.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    oyunTimer.Stop();
    KeyPreview = true;
    KeyPress += Form1OnKeyPressed;
}

private void Form1OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        oyunTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: За ранее спасибо! эти не произносимые названия на турецком)) просто меня занесло учится в Турции)) сейчас попробую))

Comment: Спасибо Огромное)) Очень помогли. А как можно вам добавить репутацию?

Comment: Вы уже озеленили мой ответ ок-стрелкой, мне этого вполне достаточно.